# How to ingest 250 tables into Kafka from MS SQL with Debezium

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Hi i have try to build Kafka connect pipeline between PostgreSQL as source to SQL Server as the destination. I used 3 Kafka brokers, and need to consume 252 topics (one topics same as one PostgreSQL table). After run for more than an hour, it only can pull 218 out of 252 tables. The error that i found is there's deadlock mechanism in SQL Server which can hold transaction to SQL Server and try to retry it, also Debezium replication slot has been there.

I use distributed connectors with 3 max worker on sink, but maybe it seems not enough. Also try with higher offset.time_out.ms to 60000 and higher offset partition (100). I'm afraid that this is not an production level that i want. Anyone can give suggestion about this case? Is there any calculation to decide best number of workers that i need?

**UPDATE**

here some error i get. I see some connectors are killed. 
One tell me that **deadlock happen in SQL SERVER** :

```
[2020-03-26 15:06:28,494] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=sql_server_sink_XXA-0} RetriableException from SinkTask: (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:552)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.RetriableException: java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 62) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:539)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 62) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

**UPDATE 14th April 2020**

I still have problem with this, i forgot to tell about how i deploy the connectors. Now i use 2 workers, one for source and one for sink. I list all of my tables and pk in an csv and loop through rows to create the connectors without sleep or wait for every minutes. I also use single topics partition and 3 replica for each topics. But i still have sql server connection deadlock

Comment: Which connectors are you using? Debezium from MSSQL, JDBC Sink to Postgres?

Comment: Debezium for Postgresql and JDBC for SQL Server

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full error that you get from Debezium? If I understand your question correctly then the issue is entirely at the ingest stage - getting the data in from MS SQL into Kafka, is that right?

Comment: that's right, the main problem is when MS SQL cannot ingest all data from kafka workers.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full error that you get from Debezium?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt this is not mainly related to Debezium after i update it, but it was JDBC connector. I still think best strategies to deploy the sink; put it at all on single workers or put it together with source at same time

Answer (score 2):

**The problem may be accessing the same SQL table with multiple tasks in the same time** and causing synchronization problems like deadlocks as you mentioned.
Since you already have a large number of topics, and your connector can access them in parallel, I would suggest you to **reduce the number partitions for every topic to just 1** (reduce number of partitions is not supported in Kafka so you should delete and recreate every topic with the new number of partitions).
This way, every topic have only one partition; every partition can be accessed only in a single thread(/task/consumer) so there is no chance for parallel SQL transactions to the same table.

Alternatively, a better approach is to **create a single topic with 3 partitions** (same as the number of tasks/consumers you have) and make the **producer use the SQL table name as the message key**.
Kafka guarantees messages with the same key to always go to the same partition, so all the messages with the same table will reside on a single partition (single thread consuming).

If you find it useful, I can attach more information about how to create Kafka Producer and send keyed messages.

Comment: Sure i want to know about it, can you send me the information?

Comment: i using java or python. For my case, i not use any programming just use pure kafka, debezium and jdbc connectors json  and zookeeper from kafka, so no additional code used.

Comment: I see that debezium connector for postgresql is automatically creates topic for every table so there is no easy way to change this behavior.  They also say "The PostgreSQL connector uses only 1 Kafka Connect partition and it places the generated events into 1 Kafka partition", so it seems to be ok. Try to set "kafkaPartition": 0

Comment: ok i will try this, so i must put all partition in kafka server config with 0, is that true?

Comment: This is in the debezium postgres connector config, not in Kafka server. https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/postgresql.html

Comment: I'm confused - Debezium is the *source* connector, and I thought MS SQL was the source here?

Comment: Debezium PostgreSQL connectors to SQL Server JDBC Conenctors

Comment: Have you tries to set "kafkaPartition": 0 in debezium postgres connector config? does it work now? I guess it was `null` before you changed it to 0

Comment: I have try with kafkaPartition:0 but there's no effect. should i create the topic first before install the connectors, or let debezium postgresql make the topic itself?

Comment: Or maybe, is there any problem with number of connection limit from postgreSQL? I have version 9.4

Comment: sorry i mean 9.5